# Mock webClient with onStatus and onError function

Tags: spring-boot, junit, webclient

When I make a thrird party call i am using webClient. But I am not able to mock the .onStatus() function call.

I tried this:

```
    @Test
void test() throws URISyntaxException {
    //GIVEN
    DtoReq requestDTO  = new DtoReq();

    WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec bodySpec = mock(WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec.class);

    given(webClient.patch()) .willReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
    given(requestBodyUriSpec.uri(anyString())) .willReturn(headerSpec);
    given(headerSpec.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)).willReturn(bodySpec);
    doReturn(body).when(bodySpec).bodyValue(requestDTO);
    given(body.retrieve()).willReturn(responseSpec);
    given(responseSpec.bodyToMono(Response.class)).willReturn(Mono.just(mock(DVAUpdateStatusResponse.class)));

    //WHEN
    integrationService.response(requestDTO);

}
```

This the the sample function i am trying to test.

```
public void toBeTested(DtoReq dtoReq) {

this.teleWebClient.patch().uri(url+ statusUpdate)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .body(Mono.just(dtoReq),DtoReq.class)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(
                HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
                return Mono.error(new RuntimeException(errorMessage));
                      
        )
        .bodyToMono(DVAUpdateStatusResponse.class)
        .doOnSuccess(res ->
                log.info("success", res)
        )
        .onErrorResume(Exception.class, exception -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("error:" + exception)))
        .toFuture();
```

}

through my testcase i am able to cover all lines except for

```
 .onStatus(
                HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
                return Mono.error(new RuntimeException(errorMessage));

        )
```

please help!